# Subset of Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a club membership database held in a google sheet which is accessible to the committee. A subset of the data is available to members via another sheet, populated using importrange.

What I need to be able to do is to withhold some rows of data from the members sheet, depending on a flag (eg a cell in the committee sheet).

It's important that when the "flag" is set, the whole record (row) in not shown in the members sheet.

I have tried some gs scripts and also =QUERY(IMPORT..) to no avail, so suggestions welcome.

Thanks

Ian

Comment: What was wrong with the query import range? If you set it to select * where x is 'ok'  that should solve your issue? If you create a dummy sheet with data I'll show you an example

Comment: hi Ian, have you tried on [WebApps Stackexchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)? i'm reluctant whether this related to programming or just using google spreadsheet.. if its the later, better to check and ask on Web Apps for your information..

Answer (score 2):

For `query` inputs that are not ranges, use `Col1`, `Col2`, etc. as column names. In your case the formula should look like:

```
=query(importrange(...),"select * where Col5 = 'N'")
```

if the *hide* flag is in 5th column and has `Y`/`N` values. Be also sure that you include the flag in the `importrange`.

Answer (score 1):

if you have **two** spreadsheets (two Google Sheets files) you need to use:

**`=IMPORTRANGE("ID or URL"; "'Sheet1'!A1:Z")`**

- **`Sheet1`** - a name of the sheet from which you want to import
- **`A1:Z`** - the range you want to import
- **`"URL"`** - whole URL address of the sheet from which you want to import

  > **example:** **`"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10asxBh4bicmqqGdIIZEguD9ApcJk4GnF82ZiS8MBkq4/edit#gid=1873076661"`**
- **`"ID"`** - part of the URL address of the sheet from which you want to import

  > **example:** **`"10asxBh4bicmqqGdIIZEguD9ApcJk4GnF82ZiS8MBkq4"`**

---

and then you can use **`FILTER`**, **`QUERY`** or both like:

```
=FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("10asxBh4bicmqqGdIIZEguD9ApcJk4GnF82ZiS8MBkq4"; "'Sheet1'!A1:Z"); 
        IMPORTRANGE("10asxBh4bicmqqGdIIZEguD9ApcJk4GnF82ZiS8MBkq4"; "'Sheet1'!C1:C") = 
        "COMPLETE")
```

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("10asxBh4bicmqqGdIIZEguD9ApcJk4GnF82ZiS8MBkq4"; "'Sheet1'!A1:Z"); 
 "select * where Col3 = 'COMPLETE'"; 0)
```

```
=FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("10asxBh4bicmqqGdIIZEguD9ApcJk4GnF82ZiS8MBkq4"; "'Sheet1'!A1:Z"); 
  QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("10asxBh4bicmqqGdIIZEguD9ApcJk4GnF82ZiS8MBkq4"; "'Sheet1'!C1:C"); 
  "select *"; 0) = "COMPLETE")
```

**side note:** **`Col3`** - column **strong text** (eg. 3rd column)